# Is there a C# library to manage a point-to-point socket connection with a unknown remote end?

Tags: sockets, tcp, netmq

I am developing an application which will open TCP/IP sockets to remote locations. For each of these connections, messages will flow in both directions asynchronously. There isn't any request-response behavior.

I've been looking at NetMQ and I like the way it manages the connecting and listening of sockets as well as the way it does the frames. But I don't see how it can work with a remote endpoint that doesn't run NetMQ.

Would defining my own socket type work? e.g.
public class MyNetMQSocket: NetMQSocket

Comment: You can use NetMQ Stream socket which is exactly for that. Use the bind and connect, it behaves like a router, but the wire is tcp, the other side can be regular tcp socket.

Comment: I wrote some code to use the StreamSocket, but I am getting some strange behavior, I will post the code.

Comment: By "strange behavior" I mean that nothing is received and that TrySend appears to sometimes succeed even when the remote end is not connected.

Comment: The first frame of Stream socket is the routing id, very similar to the router socket.